# Nordic GTK3 Theme Ubuntu doesn't work properly

Tags: 20.04, themes, gtk3

I installed [the Nordic GTK3 theme](https://github.com/EliverLara/Nordic.git), but it only applies to base software like Files, Calculator, and other default applications. It doesn't work with Discord, Spotify, etc.

I feel I should mention I configured the themes by using GNOME tweaks

The non-default applications look like this:

[image: 1]

This is what I expect to see:

[image: 2]

This is an image from someone else using this theme:

[image: 3]

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux as a whole, installed it two days ago, so please go easy on me.

Comment: Some apps just do not pay attention to themes.

Comment: my spotify also doesn't pay attention to it though, and the other person has spotify working fine

Comment: A trio questions for you: (1) which version of Ubuntu are you using (2) which version of Ubuntu is "someone else" using? (3) have you [reported the issue to the developer](https://github.com/EliverLara/Nordic/issues)? They would be in a much better position to answer the question than most of the people here 

Comment: (1) 20.04 
(2) Not sure, but the screenshot was uploaded on November 3, 2020. Here: https://www.deviantart.com/methane2264/art/Ubuntu-Nord-Theme-860088410
(3) No I have not, I found it much more likely that it was an error by me rather than the creator of the pack.

Comment: One of the many drawbacks of snaps: they ignore user themes (they only support a basic theme set)

Comment: kanehekili, yeah I actually just saw another post about snap files not respecting themes. I reinstalled Spotify using apt and it hasn't fixed anything

Comment: So...... I restarted my PC, and it worked. My bad guys, should've been the first thing I did

Comment: Yes. I agree... LMAO. Restarting the PC has a tendency to be a global solution for everything. Don't worry, we've all forgotten about that at some point.